# frequency table of multiple similar datasets for a common column

Tags: r, apply

How to get frequency table of multiple datasets `msleep`, `msleep_sub` for a common column `vore`? I was wondering if this can be achieved by passing column name to `apply` family functions.

```
library(msleep)
head(msleep)
msleep_sub <- msleep %>% group_by(genus) %>% filter(n() ==1)
table(msleep$vore)
#   carni   herbi insecti    omni 
#      14      27       5      20
table(msleep_sub$vore)
#   carni   herbi insecti    omni 
#      19      32       5      20
```

More precisely, how to get the above two outputs using a single command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We keep the objects in a `list` and get the `table` of the required column by looping through the `list` with `lapply`

```
lapply(list(msleep, msleep_sub), function(x) table(x$vore))
```

---

Or another option is `tidyverse` after keeping the objects in a `list`

```
library(tidyverse)
list(msleep, msleep_sub) %>%
             map(~table(.$vore))
```

---

If we need a named `list`

```
mget(ls(pattern = "msleep")) %>% 
                  map(~table(.$vore))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun, I can only accept the answer after 10min. I overlooked and missed passing `x` in the above command while trying different approaches. Would be interesting to know if the items in the list can be named with their corresponding dataframe names.

Comment: @Prradep  Updated the post